# Recursive query to get all parent records in lookup relationship

Tags: apex, recursion

Let's say we have parent__c field in MyObject__c object that is lookup to itself. Is it possible to get all parents for particular child (highest parent has null value for parent__c)

Comment: is it possible? yes. You can [edit] your question to provide any attempts/code you've started, any errors you're getting, or where exactly you're struggling in achieving this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, SOQL only allows us to query up 5 levels in a hierarchy, so if there's a chance that you have a deeper hierarchy then a single SOQL query won't cut it (without additional processing).

If you have fewer than 50k records total for this object, you could simply query them all and build a `Map<Id, MyObject__c>`. Afterwords, you can start at any record and just `myMap.get(childRecord.Parent__c)` until `Parent__c` is null.

Above that limit, you'll need to get a bit more creative. For example, when I needed to handle a similar situation (start with a single IPv4 address, merge it into ever larger blocks of IP addresses until we hit one of our collection of ultimate "parent" blocks that we've been allocated from ARIN), I:

- added a field to hold the Id of the ultimate parent record
- had some anonymous apex that started at the ultimate parent and
  propagated that value down to all of its descendants (children,
  grandchildren, great-grandchildren, etc...)

The idea there was that by knowing which parent is at the end of the chain ahead of time, we can reduce the number of rows that we'd need to query by filtering on `utlimate_parent__c = :child.ultimate_parent__c`.

I imagine there are other creative approaches like that to help you with queries on large hierarchies, and the approach you'd take would be pretty specific to how your hierarchy is organized (my IP address example is effectively a binary tree, each parent has precisely 2 children).

At any rate though, multiple queries is something I might only consider as a last resort.